# how to cause submit on click input fields? Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I need to submit a form to the click input fields because I want to receive a message that will inform the user what types are required to submit a form.
Chek my code:

```
<form @submit.prevent="SubmitForm"
 <input type="text" placeholder="enter name">
<button type="submit"> submit </button>
```

On click on input type I need to submit form, how???
I try with @click on input but without success
and my validation bellow..I using Vuelidate...

```
SubmitForm() { 
  this.submitted = true; 
  // stop here if form is invalid
  this.$v.$touch();

  if (this.$v.$invalid) {
    return;
  }
   ....code
}


 validations: {
    user: {
       name: {required } // this is in data() return ...
     }
   }
```

Comment: This should work fine. Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using codesandbox or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening?

Comment: i think you're missing a v-model on input, probably v-model="user.name"

Comment: Okay this is only demostration. How to do this question ?